# Cost Associated with Increasing API Request Quota for YouTube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on an application to create livestreams on YouTube and retrieve their comments. However, I might need to increase the API request quota. Is there any fee associated with this quota increase?

I have searched on youtube and google documentation and I haven't found anything about it.

Comment: [Requesting additional quota is free.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)